# My fonts are looking bolder on my MAC

Tags: html, media-queries, google-font-api

I have a website [website page](http://vigosol.com/webtest/blabbr/create-chat-step-1.html) designed and connected the google fonts, my fonts look good on windows but on MAC its looking much bolder ... how can I fix this issue...[open the link to see the screen-shot of the difference](http://s1.postimg.org/u4rhm2skd/Screen_Ruler_658_E5_A7_A_CED6_489_B_8_B80_912_EA907_AF49.png)

Comment: different browsers and platforms render differently.

Comment: is there any solution for this ?

Comment: See my answer and link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appearance of bolder text on a Mac is a result of differences in the text-rendering algorithms used by each OS.

You may be able to use the -webkit-font-smoothing css property - see [this link](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/06/12.html) for further explanation.